# Existence of a homeomorphism between two subspaces of real line

Tags: general-topology

Can we say the set of natural numbers is homeomorphic to the set of integers?
A map $f$ from $N$ to $Z$ defined $f(n)=-n$ does not work.
Could you give me any hint?

Comment: Are you looking for a bijection or a homeomorphism? If the latter, you need to specify a topology of sorts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: **Any** bijection works, since both sets have the discrete topology. Try matching up the even natural numbers with the non-negative integers and the odd natural numbers with the negative integers, for instance.

Comment: there exists no odd natural numbers? what do you mean?

Comment: Some natural numbers are very odd...

Comment: @ege: Of course there are odd natural numbers: I even mentioned them! You want a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Z$; I’m suggesting that you try to find one that sends every even natural number to a non-negative integer and every odd natural number to a negative integer. Look at $0,1,2,3,4,5,\dots$ and $0,-1,1,-2,2,-3,\dots$ for more inspiration.

Comment: what about  the set of rationals? Is it homeomorphic to the set of integers?

Comment: @ege: Definitely not. $\Bbb N$ is discrete: every singleton $\{n\}$ is an open set. Is $\{q\}$ ever an open subset of $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: If the topology on the rationals is standard topology,can we say is it homeomorphic to the set of integers or reals with respect to the standard topology?

Comment: @ege: No, definitely not. I just explained why it can’t be homeomorphic to the integers. It can’t be homeomorphic to the reals simply because $\Bbb Q$ is a countable set, and $\Bbb R$ isn’t: there isn’t even a bijection between them, let alone a homeomorphism.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott does this require the set N to contain {0} ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Natural numbers can be even or odd. Integers can be positive or negative.

Comment: sorry because of the misunterstanding. thanks, now its clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try $\phi(n) = (-1)^n \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$. Then $\phi:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is a bijection.